# Groovy's Ivy cache (@Grab) not caching?

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I'm running this simply groovy script using groovyConsole (version 1.8.1):

```
println "Start " + new Date()
@Grab( 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16' )
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
println "End " + new Date()
```

Usually, it executes very quickly (~ 0 seconds).

However, sometimes (once every ~5 runs), it pauses for 3-5 seconds before completing the run.
I'm sniffing with Wireshark ([here is the capture](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/464119/Programming/Maven/grab.pcap)), and see HTTP requests to `repository.codehaus.org` (I see some 404 responses in the Wireshark stream, but the script manages to run, so evidently the jars are found at some point)

My question is - once the script runs once, aren't the jars it download via @Grab cached forever? Why is the actual Ivy/Maven repository queried so often?

Comment: Is that all you `@Grab` in the script? I only ask, as Ivy (which underpins `@Grab`) seems to be looking for loads of unrelated packages. I'm no Ivy expert though :-/

Comment: @tim_yates - yes, that's the entire script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files should be cached in `~/.groovy/grapes`.  If you rerun your script with `-Divy.message.logger.level=4`, you'll get some debug information from ivy that may be helpful.

Additionally, if you have a grape that takes a long time to resolve, you can tell ivy to check less often.  Copy the default ivy config from [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/resources/groovy/grape/defaultGrapeConfig.xml) to `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml` and add the property `ivy.cache.ttl.default` to some length of time to wait before checking again.  For example:

```
<ivysettings>
  <property name="ivy.cache.ttl.default" value="24h"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="downloadGrapes" returnFirst="true">
      <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
        <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
        <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
      </filesystem>
      <ibiblio name="localm2" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" checkmodified="true" changingPattern=".*" changingMatcher="regexp" m2compatible="true"/>
      <!-- todo add 'endorsed groovy extensions' resolver here -->
      <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
      <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```